# unix command to extract digits after last alphabetical string

Tags: shell

String:"gamma021AH00999NAK41"
last two digit may vary.It may be 3 digit 4 digit ,etc...
"NAK" in the given string  can be any other string but it contains only characters.
So my intention is to extract last numbers(example 41 in the given string) until first character.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What do you mean *until first character*, are there any other characters after those last digits?

Comment: sorry,i mean in reverse order

Comment: Please ignore this question

Comment: Instead of requesting to ignore the question, you can delete it if you want, just by clicking "delete".

Comment: ...though once it's answered, it's no longer good form to delete if the question and its answers could be helpful to someone else; the whole reason Stack Overflow exists is to build a knowledge base.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy ok but then I was going to say the question is confusing: "... but it contains only characters" - all strings contain nothing _but_ characters, that's what strings are made of!

Answer (score 1):

You can replace all the alphabetic characters by for example "#" and then take the last field based on the "#" separator:

```
echo "gamma021AH00999NAK41" | sed "s/[aA-zZ]/#/g" | awk -F'#' '{print $NF}'
```

NOTE: This won't work if you have other than alphanumeric symbols in your string.

EDIT: Only without `awk` (Thanks @CharlesDuffy):

```
echo "gamma021AH00999NAK41" | awk -F'[[:alpha:]]' '{print $NF}'
```

Comment: There's no reason for the `sed`; you could run `awk -F'[[:alpha:]]' '{print $NF}'` with the same effect.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Thanks, I was sure that it was possible to do it like that, but didn't find it.

Comment: (`[aA-zZ]` is a new one on me; it's clever, in that it works correctly both with locales where ordering is like `aAbB...zZ` and ones where it's like `abc...zABC...Z` -- but probably better to just use named character classes, and not need the cleverness; I don't know if `AaBb...Zz` locales exist, but if they do, it would break down there).

Answer (score 1):

Using only shell builtins (no external commands like `sed` or `awk`, thus much faster if you're going to be repeating this over and over, f/e, once per line):

```
s=gamma021AH00999NAK41
result=${s##*[[:alpha:]]}
echo "$result"
```

`${var##pattern}` is a [parameter expansion](https://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe#substring_removal) which removes the longest possible match for `pattern` from the front of the value of `var` before returning it. `*[[:alpha:]]`, as a wildcard followed by an alpha character, will thus remove everything before the `K` in your string.

Answer (score 1):

I see no mention of varying length, so this command will work:

```
echo "gamma021AH00999NAK41" | cut -b '19-'
```

Answer : 41